# Timezone issue with scheduled chat notifications

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, email-notification

I got an email notification at noon today saying a scheduled chat was going to happen in 2 hours.

The chat is actually scheduled for 8 pm UTC and it translates into 3 pm my time, not 2 pm. The notification should've said the chat was starting in 3 hours.

I am in the [EST (Toronto) timezone](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/city.html?n=250). Is there a timezone setting I missed somewhere or is this a notification bug?

Comment: Hmm... similar bug reported yesterday, [in chat](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/514085#514085). (Thanks for the assist, @TimStone.)

Comment: My initial wild speculation is that this is a not-accounting-for-daylight-savings-conversion bug, but it's not like I have access to the code.

Comment: Chat doesn't know (or care about) your time zone. "in 2 hours" just means "in less than 3 hours, but in at least 2 hours"

Comment: @balpha I have trouble accepting that behaviour as correct. If there are no assumptions made about the recipient's timezone (which is fair), I believe it shouldn't say "in 2 hours" and just say something like "later today". The scheduled start time in UTC is already listed and should be sufficient. Otherwise I think the message is misleading.

Comment: If my intent was to say "This behaviour is correct", I would've posted that as an answer, not as a comment. All I wanted is offer some explanation as to why you're seeing what you're seeing.

Comment: @balpha Sorry, I was just trying to say that current behaviour is odd at best. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: I've reported a similiar issue with chat events a bit ago: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78269/chat-gets-confused-about-tomorrow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We now round the hours correctly (instead of picking just the non-fractional part), i.e. "in 2 hours and 58 minutes" translates to "3 hours". Also note that the room's schedule page (which is linked from the email) now [shows the event's date in the user's timezone](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91712/please-display-a-more-useful-time-for-chat-events/93288#93288).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that SE piggybacks on one of the many time converting systems for upcoming chat events (the only situation where timezones really do matter), like this:

> Starts Saturday at [18:00 UTC](http://time.is/1800_in_UTC), lasts 120 minutes.
>
> Starts tomorrow at [18:00 UTC](http://time.is/1800_in_UTC), lasts 120 minutes.
>
> Starts today at [18:00 UTC](http://time.is/1800_in_UTC), lasts 120 minutes.
>
> Starts in 59 minutes, lasts 120 minutes.

Comment: Please note that while time.is has a few nice touches like detecting your timezone correctly, it _will_ be misleading when organizing events on March as the US moves to DST and the EU doesn't.