# Please display a more useful time for chat events

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, chat

The description of a scheduled chat event, on the [room schedule page](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/198/science-fiction-fantasy?tab=schedule), displays the event UTC date and the amount of time left before the event starts in a “human-friendly” way. A mouse-over tip shows the precise time in UTC.

[image]

On the [event listing page](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms?tab=events&sort=active), there's the approximate amount of time before the event, and that's it.

But if I'm planning to attend an event, knowing that it's “Wednesday at 9pm” is a lot more helpful than “in 19 hours”.

Please display a more helpful time. I suggest:

- “on <date> at <time>” if the event is not on the same calendar day in local time.
- at <time> if the event is today (local time).
- in N minutes if the event is in less than an hour.

(Keep the UTC date as the mouse-over text.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image: scheduled chat event with local time]

Comment: I'm assuming that it still uses 24-hour time regardless of time zone?

Comment: @GraceNote: Yes. Jeff and I debated that, but since it's the same in the live chat, it made sense to stay consistent.

Answer (score 0):

This implies we know your local time zone, which we don't.

All our times are in UTC.

Comment: Any reason why you can't use Javascript to convert from UTC to local time in the browser?

Comment: @kyle I don't want to -- I prefer everything in relative times and UTC. Probably the same reason the iPhone has one button and not, say, a back button..

Comment: But the timestamps in the actual chat rooms seem to be in local time, no? Not when you browse the archives, only when you participate in the chat.

Comment: @jan that's a fair point